# Replace string in pandas df column name

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe in pandas, with columns named "string_string", I'm trying to rename them by removing the "_" and the following string.  For example, I want to change "12527_AC9E5" to "12527".  I've tried to use various replace options, and I can replace a specific part of the string (e.g., I can replace all the "_"), but when I introduce wildcards I do not achieve the desired result.

Below are some of the things I thought would work, but don't.   If I remove the wild cards they work (i.e, they replace the _).

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.sub('_.+', ''))

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_.+','')
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 18):

Just split on '_' and take the first element. You can take advantage of dictionary comprehension:

```
df = df.rename(columns={col: col.split('_')[0] for col in df.columns})
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question!  Can any light be shed on why the replace using wildcards doesn't work?  The reason I ask is that I can perform the task I'm trying to do very easily using Perl, but am getting a bit muddled trying to understand python regex stuff........

Comment: @DeepSpace what if one of the column doesn't contain '_' , it will give me an error "IndexError: list index out of range"  please advise how to handle it

Comment: @PyBoss You should not get that error since splitting on a non-existing character still returns a list with a single element. Please open a new question with your exact issue